# Why is Linux Mint using my laptop's microphone despite a headphone being plugged in?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint, microphone

I have an Asus GL553VD laptop, which has a combined 3.5mm jack for shared input and output.

When on Windows, upon plugging in the device, it'll automatically detect it as Headphones, and use it's microphone. On some devices, it may ask me to specify, headphones or headset, and if headset is chosen, the mic is used.

When on Linux Mint, however, it completely ignores the headset's microphone and uses the one integrated within the laptop. "Sound" has no relevant settings, only input selection (for context, on windows, it only ever shows up as the same device, I believe the driver switches it in the background).

I have a theory that, if I somehow tell Mint that this is a headset, it'll work correctly. How could that be done?

Alternatively, what else could it be?